# Service function onLocationChanged() return 0.0 coordinates in AsyncTask

Tags: android, location, latitude-longitude

In my application for android and have a service and asynctask. I use PostData AsyncTask to send data to the server in several ways:

1. Manual method with MainActivity by the following construction:

   ```
   protected void onResume() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onResume();

       //10_06_2013
       //Останавливаем наш сервис определения координат
       Intent intentstop = new Intent(this,GPSTracker.class);
       stopService(intentstop);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service STOP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Test
       //Стартуем наш сервис определения координат
       Intent intentstart = new Intent(this,GPSTracker.class);
       startService(intentstart);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service START", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Test
       // Gets the user's network preference settings
       SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       //Здесь берутся из настроек Параметры отвечающие за позиционирования разрешено или нет
       Boolean GPSnotif = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("location_share_enordis", true);
       //проверяем наличие файла если его нет то координаты не отправляются 12_06_2013 //______This block work
       String FILELOGIN = "TeleportSAASUser.txt";
       File filelogin = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(FILELOGIN);
       if (filelogin.exists()) {
       //______This block work

       if (GPSnotif.equals(true)) {
           GPSdetermination();
           new PostData(gps, RD, getBaseContext()).execute();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.location_send_toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       else {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.share_location_NO, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       }
       else {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.check_user_profile_toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

   }
   ```
2. Automatic method onLocationChanged when changing the user's position which is in my GPSTracker class

   ```
   public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
   private final Context mContext;

   //определяем переменную главного активити
       MainActivity ma;
       GPSTracker gps;
       Teleport_user_profile_activity UP;
       ReadData RD;
       PostData PD;
       Context rdContext;

   // flag for GPS status
   boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

   // flag for network status
   boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

   // flag for GPS status
   boolean canGetLocation = false;

   Location location; // location
   double latitude; // latitude
   double longitude; // longitude

   // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
   private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

   // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
   private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 0;; // 0 minute

   // Declaring a Location Manager
   protected LocationManager locationManager;

   public GPSTracker(Context context) {
       this.mContext = context;
       getLocation();
   }

   public static String UserLoginFile;
   public static String UserPassFile;

   // Функция для определения местоположения
   public Location getLocation() {
       try {
           locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                   .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

           // getting GPS status
           isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                   .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

           // getting network status
           isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                   .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

           if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
               // no network provider is enabled
           } else {
               this.canGetLocation = true;
               if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                           LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                           MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                           MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                   Log.d("Network", "Network");
                   if (locationManager != null) {
                       location = locationManager
                               .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                       if (location != null) {
                           latitude = location.getLatitude();
                           longitude = location.getLongitude();
                       }
                   }
               }
               // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
               if (isGPSEnabled) {
                   if (location == null) {
                       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                               LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                               MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                               MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                       Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                       if (locationManager != null) {
                           location = locationManager
                                   .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                           if (location != null) {
                               latitude = location.getLatitude();
                               longitude = location.getLongitude();
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return location;
   }
   /**
    * Stop using GPS listener
    * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
    * */
   public void stopUsingGPS(){
       if(locationManager != null){
           locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
       }       
   }

   /**
    * Function to get latitude
    * */
   public double getLatitude(){
       if(location != null){
           latitude = location.getLatitude();
       }

       // return latitude
       return latitude;
   }

   /**
    * Function to get longitude
    * */
   public double getLongitude(){
       if(location != null){
           longitude = location.getLongitude();
       }

       // return longitude
       return longitude;
   }

   /**
    * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
    * @return boolean
    * */
   public boolean canGetLocation() {
       return this.canGetLocation;
   }

   /**
    * Function to show settings alert dialog
    * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
    * */
   public void showSettingsAlert(){
       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

       // Setting Dialog Title
       alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

       // Setting Dialog Message
       alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

       // On pressing Settings button
       alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
               mContext.startActivity(intent);
           }
       });

       // on pressing cancel button
       alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           dialog.cancel();
           }
       });

       // Showing Alert Message
       alertDialog.show();
   }



   //события которые происходят если позиция поменялась
   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       this.location = location;

     //Здесь берутся из настроек Параметры отвечающие за позиционирования разрешено или нет
       SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("location_share_enordis", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       Boolean GPSnotif = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("location_share_enordis", true);

       if (GPSnotif.equals(true)) {
           //Отправка местоположения если позиция изменилась 10_06_2013____This block work
           GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this); // работает
           new PostData(gps, RD, mContext).execute();
           //Test to LogCat
           Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED_IN_GPSTracker_Latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
           Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED_IN_GPSTracker_Longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");
       } 
       else {

       }


   }


   @Override
   public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
   }

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
       return null;
   }
   ```

   }

LogCat

```
06-12 10:01:31.656: D/GPS Enabled(2077): GPS Enabled
06-12 10:01:31.715: D/Start AsyncTask PostData(2077): Started
06-12 10:01:31.715: D/LOCATION_IN_PostData_Latitude(2077): 49.422005000000006
06-12 10:01:31.715: D/LOCATION_IN_PostData_Longitude(2077): -129.08409333333333
06-12 10:01:31.936: I/Choreographer(2077): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-12 10:01:31.945: D/gralloc_goldfish(2077): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-12 10:01:32.495: I/Choreographer(2077): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-12 10:01:33.255: E/Web Console(2077): Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored. at http://myheart.pp.ua/:8
06-12 10:01:33.255: V/Web Console(2077): Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. at http://myheart.pp.ua/:8
06-12 10:01:33.255: V/Web Console(2077): Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "maximum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. at http://myheart.pp.ua/:8
06-12 10:01:33.275: V/Web Console(2077): Viewport argument value "0;" for key "user-scalable" was truncated to its numeric prefix. at http://myheart.pp.ua/:8
06-12 10:01:34.265: D/dalvikvm(2077): GC_CONCURRENT freed 231K, 4% free 8194K/8519K, paused 30ms+110ms, total 191ms
06-12 10:01:34.985: W/SingleClientConnManager(2077): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
06-12 10:01:34.985: W/SingleClientConnManager(2077): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
06-12 10:01:50.095: W/System.err(2077): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 10:01:50.095: W/System.err(2077):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:416)
06-12 10:01:50.095: W/System.err(2077):     at com.teleport.saas.GPSTracker.getLocation(GPSTracker.java:70)
06-12 10:01:50.095: W/System.err(2077):     at com.teleport.saas.GPSTracker.<init>(GPSTracker.java:60)
06-12 10:01:50.095: W/System.err(2077):     at com.teleport.saas.GPSTracker.onLocationChanged(GPSTracker.java:214)
06-12 10:01:50.095: W/System.err(2077):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:237)
06-12 10:01:50.095: W/System.err(2077):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:170)
06-12 10:01:50.106: W/System.err(2077):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:186)
06-12 10:01:50.106: W/System.err(2077):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 10:01:50.106: W/System.err(2077):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 10:01:50.106: W/System.err(2077):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-12 10:01:50.106: W/System.err(2077):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 10:01:50.106: W/System.err(2077):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-12 10:01:50.106: W/System.err(2077):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-12 10:01:50.106: W/System.err(2077):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-12 10:01:50.106: W/System.err(2077):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 10:01:50.125: D/LOCATION CHANGED_IN_GPSTracker_Latitude(2077): 11.422005000000002
06-12 10:01:50.125: D/LOCATION CHANGED_IN_GPSTracker_Longitude(2077): -111.084095
06-12 10:01:50.135: D/Start AsyncTask PostData(2077): Started
06-12 10:01:50.135: D/LOCATION_IN_PostData_Latitude(2077): 0.0
06-12 10:01:50.135: D/LOCATION_IN_PostData_Longitude(2077): 0.0
06-12 10:01:50.315: W/SingleClientConnManager(2077): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
06-12 10:01:50.315: W/SingleClientConnManager(2077): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
```

When using the manual method of sending coordinates to the server. The coordinates are obtained by means of functions gps.getLatitude(); gps.getLongitude(); and sent correctly as shown by LogCat.
But as soon as the need to update the coordinates of the automatic method, they fall into the function onLocationChanged()

```
LOCATION CHANGED_IN_GPSTracker_Latitude(2077): 11.422005000000002
LOCATION CHANGED_IN_GPSTracker_Longitude(2077): -111.084095
```

but they are null (0.0) in PostData AsyncTask

```
06-12 10:01:50.135: D/LOCATION_IN_PostData_Latitude(2077): 0.0
06-12 10:01:50.135: D/LOCATION_IN_PostData_Longitude(2077): 0.0
```

I can not understand the reason why the function in my AsyncTask receives the null (0.0) Latitude and Longitude. Please help me to solve my problem. What changes should I make to my code to my AsyncTask took the correct Latitude and Longitude values by automatic data send method.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use :

```
LocationManager loc = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)
```

to get the service.

Then LocationListener followed by the class which implement it.like =>

```
LocationListener listener = new MyLocationListener();
```

Then fetch updates through your requestLocationUpdates method. like =>

```
loc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, your minimum time, your minimum distance, listener)
```

Don't forget to create the inner class MyLocationListener which must be implements the LocationListener  interface.like =>

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //**fetch all your latitudes and longitudes through location object**        }

   @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    //**do our show something when gps is disabled** 

   }

  @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

   }
  @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

  //**Do/Show something when status changed i.e provider is unable to fetch data** 
   }
```

..........
Add this codes at first to enable gps and wifi if they are disabled.

To enable GPS:

```
     String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if (!provider.contains("gps")) {
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");

        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
```

And about WIFI:

```
     WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

      if (!wm.isWifiEnabled()) {
        wm.setWifiEnabled(true);
      } else {
         // for disable when requir
         wm.setWifiEnabled(false);
      }
```

If you will do a simple thing with a hard manner, then it will must make you confusion.

**All the best**